# A conjecture about homotopy $S^1\times B^3$'s

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, 4-manifolds, embeddings

$\textbf{Conjecture}:$

Let $X^4$ be a homotopy $S^1\times B^3$ with the following properties:

1. Attaching a four dimensional 2-handle gives a standard $B^4$.
2. The $k$-fold cyclic cover is diffeomorphic to the standard $S^1\times B^3$, for some $k>1$.

Then, $X^4$ is diffeomorphic to $S^1\times B^3$.

I first thought that this was true, but my argument was assuming $X^4$ was fibered, which I don't know is true or how to show. In this case you could use the $k$-fold covering to smoothly embed a $B^3$, then use property 1 to conclude you don't have a homotopy 4-ball with a 1-handle attached.

I had a second idea, which is to use the fact that $X^4$ is smoothly s-cobordant to $S^1\times B^3$, use this to build an s-cobordism between the two k-fold coverings, and apply Shaneson's results that the s-cobordism upstairs has to be a smooth product, then somehow get this product structure to descend smoothly, or use it to get a smooth proper embedding of $B^3$ into $X^4$, as this would be enough. I'm not sure if such an approach could work and I'd appreciate some input, regarding either if the conjecture above is known to be false, equivalent to something super hard (4DSP?), or if the approach could work.

*Shaneson, J. L.*, [**Embedding with codimension two of spheres in spheres and (h)-cobordisms of (S^ 1\times S^ 3)**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1968-12107-X), Bull. Am. Math. Soc. 74, 972-974 (1968). [ZBL0167.21602](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0167.21602).

$\textbf{Edit:}$

As Ian Agol points out below, there is some relation to the Smith conjecture. Note by property 1 that $X^4$ arises by carving out a neighborhood of some slice disk in $B^4$. As the boundary of $X^4$ is $S^1\times S^2$ (follows from property 2), Property-r for 1 knots implies this disk has to be a slice disk for the unknot. Now, if you take the $k$-fold cyclic branch cover of $B^4$, branched over this disk, it's unknotted (property 2).

Now the Generalized Smith conjecture says that, given an $n$-sphere embedded in $S^{n+2}$. If the k-fold cyclic cover branched over $S^n$ is $S^{n+2}$, then $S^{n}$ is unknotted. This is known to be false in dimension 4 (when n = 2 as stated). So the above conjecture is asking if the Smith conjecture holds (smoothly) if you know the 2-knot is topologically unknotted. I'm not sure if it's known that all topologically unknots are virtually unknotted, so I don't think it's obviously equivalent to the smooth unknotting conjecture.

Comment: Does "k-fold cyclic" mean "k-fold cyclic cover?"

Comment: Yes it does, I'll fix the typo.

Comment: A couple of small points that I wondered about but you must have considered. 1. Why is the boundary of your $X$ is $S^1 \times S^2$? This follows from the fact that the boundary has a finite cyclic cover that's $S^1 \times S^2$.  2. Why is X smoothly s-cobordant to $S^1 \times B^3$? This follows because the s-cobordism classification is given by a codimension-one Rochlin invariant, and that is invariant under taking of finite cyclic covers in this setting.

Comment: This seems to be related to the generalized Smith conjecture. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmithConjecture.html

Comment: @DannyRuberman So, I had not considered your two points prior to posting the question. This came up while working on something else. In that setup, I know 1 and 2 are true (for different reasons), but wasn't sure if the conjecture was true or not.

Comment: If your $X^4$ is fibered (over the circle), then it's $S^1 \times B^3$. That's because the fiber would have to be contractible, and hence (by the 3-dimensional Poincaré conjecture) $B^3$. But (I think it's implicit that your $X$ is orientable) since the orientation-preserving diffeomorphism group of $B^3$ is connected,  it must be a trivial fibering.

Comment: @DannyRuberman Is there a good way to show something is smoothly fibered over the circle? I could provide more context if needed.

Comment: @DanielH.Hartman some context seems like a good idea.

Comment: @DanielH.Hartman: there is Farrell's fibering theorem, if you want to prove fibering in a "passive" way using invariants.  It is not known to be true for 4-manifolds, but it works for high-dimensional manifolds.  In dimension 4, the only thing I know is that you constrruct the fibering "by hands", i.e. explicit maps and checking smoothness, etc.

Comment: @RyanBudney It's known that the Farrell fibering theorem fails in the topological category in dimension 4. I gave examples in Seifert surfaces of knots in $S^4$. Pacific J. Math. 145 (1990), no. 1, 97–116 with fundamental group $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_3$; the same method works for $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ for any $n>2$. These manifolds are not known to be smoothable, though.

Comment: @DannyRuberman: that's great Danny.  Thank-you for your helpful work.

Comment: @DannyRuberman  Here is a little more context. Suppose you have two embedded 3-spheres in $S^4$ which bound smooth 4-balls each, and intersect along a genus 1 handle body (an $S^1\times B^2$), which is unknotted in both 3-spheres.  The question is, can you isotope one 3-sphere to the other, keeping the genus 1 handle body fixed? Decomposing $S^4$ appropriately, you get two embedded $S^1\times B^2$'s in $S^1\times B^3$ which agree on their boundary. After an isotopy, you can assume they are disjoint except on their boundaries (may this isn't obvious, but you can do this).

Comment: They naturally split (by Freedman and a little calculation) $S^1\times B^3$ into a 4-manifold which is homeomorphic to $S^1\times B^3$ (the region between the two embeddings). If this manifold is diffeomorphic to $S^1\times B^3$, then the two embeddings are isotopic.